# Как работает прокси сервер?

Tags: сервер, веб-сервер, proxy

Я хочу самостоятельно(для собственного развития) написать сервер для раздачи статики с возможностью проксировать запросы на бэк. У меня есть вопросы по логике работы данного сервера, как я понимаю, такой сервер одновременно является как сервером, так и клиентом. Т.е когда к нему приходит запрос на динамический контент, он просто дублирует данный запрос другому серверу, который может его обработать, а потом дублирует ответ клиенту? Так ли это, или существует логика по передаче именно соединения другому серверу? Насколько я понимаю, передать соединение возможно в рамках одной машинки(по unix сокетам), но не по tcp.

Comment: Передавать соединение не надо, почти каждый прокси-сервер просто создаёт новый http-запрос и отправляет его бэку как обычный клиент

Comment: Но и не полностью дублирует, в зависимости от желаемого поведения запрос может незначительно (или значительно) измениться, ответ тоже

Comment: В зависимости от выбранной платформы (ну, грубо говоря, языка) сложность задачи будет разная. На node.js или пайтоне это будет занимать несколько строк. На C# - видимо, несколько десятков строк. На С++ придётся подключить какую нибудь библиотеку для HTTP, и код займет, думаю, около сотни строк. А так - задача поучительная, делитесь результатами потом! Правда, это - без проксирования. Но проксировать резльтаты GET запросов - это не очень сложно, я думаю. Но значительная часть запросов на динамический контент идет через POST, и тут с проксированием - сложнее.

Comment: @andreymal а можно два сокета сцепить через sendfile?